# Number of combinations when you can choose none or multiple options for a questions.

Tags: combinatorics

I would like to know both the formula and the math name for such combination. Simple example: 1 questions with 3 options, you can choose none, one or multiple options. How can I calculate the number of combinations in such case.

Comment: How many binary number can be formed with three bits? $(1+1)^3$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider a set $S$ with options $\{a,b, c\}$. The [power set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set) of $S$ is the set of all possible subsets, viz $\{\varnothing, \{a\}, \{b\},\{c\}, \{a,b\}, \{a,c\}, \{b,c\}, \{a,b, c\}\}$. If there are $n$ options, then there are $2^n$ choices.

**Proof**: Consider the set $S$. For each subset, we have $2$ choices, we can either include the option, or not include the option. By the fundamental principle of counting, we multiply these to get that there are $2^{|S|}$ choices.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you question has options $a$, $b$, and $c$. What you are looking for is just the subsets of the set $\{a,b,c\}$. These are $\emptyset$, $\{a\}$, $\{b\}$, $\{c\}$, $\{a,b\}$, $\{a,c\}$, $\{b,c\}$, $\{a,b,c\}$. Given $n$ options, there are $2^n$ of these. In particular, $\emptyset$ corresponds to the case where none of the options are true.